# How to configure tomcat 8.5 in Amazon EC2 Instance to support HTTPS

Tags: amazon-ec2, https

I am a beginner in developing server side application. Now I ran into a problem in dealing with HTTPS connections to our Tomcat server.

I followed the guide in the [official site of Apache Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/ssl-howto.html) to configure Tomcat to support HTTPS, and of course other tutorials about this, but weren't able to get this done.

I will summarize the steps I did:

1. Use keytool of java to generate a keystore with password by
   executing the following command:

   ```
   keytool -genkey -alias tomcat -keyalg RSA -keystore tomcat
   ```
2. After generating the keystore, I will edit the config file of tomcat
   like as follows:

   ```
   <Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
              maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
              clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"
              keystoreFile="/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_102.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/tomcat"
              keystorePass="passwordOfTheKeyStore" />
   ```

Then when I test this by accessing https://34.196.30.187:8443/server/login.html, the browser will display this

Even when I test this locally, the result is the same.

[image]

Comment: Please expand on "not working". Does the browser give an error? Does Tomcat not start? Can you show a curl with response headers and the corresponding access / error logs? Is there anything relevant in the tomcat error logs?

Comment: @Tim Hi, I just edited my question

Comment: Read my previous comment again. I see no logs. The error message in the browser looks like a pretty good clue to me.

Comment: @Tim Hi, I hope there were logs but there seems to be no logs at all so I myself find it hard to solve this problem. I

Comment: Problem solving step no1 - work out how to turn the log on. If you need to you can start from a clean install.

Comment: ideally people will prefer to configure ssl on domain name not on IP with port number. So better update your configuration to access URL with domain name. There you can redirect all the request coming on 443 of apache to backend tomcat on port using AJP connector.